# Get the column value by considering multiple delimiters in MySQL and Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

```
Invoice No

12345/1

789_2
```

The output i require is as follows

```
Invoice No

12345

789
```

Kindly help me to achieve the above result using mysql and laravel 5.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, we can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to conditionally take the substring of the invoice depending on the presence/absence of separator characters:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN invoice_no LIKE '%/%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_no, '/', 1)
         WHEN invoice_no LIKE '%\\\\%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_no, '\\', 1)
         WHEN invoice_no LIKE '%\_%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_no, '_', 1)
         ELSE invoice_no END AS invoice_no_new
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: i am not able to consider a backslash as a delimiter i.e., 789\2

Comment: 12345\1 results to 123451 which is not my required answer.

Comment: @Thilagam I updated my answer.  You need to doubly escape backslash in a `LIKE` expression.